# Fragment getActivity() -- avoiding NPE

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I have a single Activity application with a number of Fragments (15 or so). Some of the methods in my `MyActivity` are required  by all the Fragments, such as displaying `Dialogs`. So what I have in a sample call from a Fragment (and they all extend `MyFragment`) is something like:

`getMyActivity().displayDialog(msg);`

and `getMyActivity` is defined as in `MyFragment`:

```
MyActivity getMyActivity() {
  return (MyActivity) getActivity();
}
```

however, sometimes getActivity() is null so I get NPEs in that case.  So what I'm doing is moving those methods into MyFragment such that:

```
protected void displayDialog(String msg) {
  if (getMyActivity() != null) {
     getMyActivity().displayDialog(msg);
  } else {
     // what do I do here?
  }
}
```

Does this approach make sense for the 10 or so methods I need to reference from MyActivity (and are there any pitfalls to doing so)? Also, what would I do to provide feedback in the case where `getActivity()` is null?

Edit: A common example of a cause for a NullPointerException would be something like a network call being dispatched by the Fragment and on completion of said network call, trying to display a Dialog when the `Activity` was destroyed in the meantime.

Comment: That works it would be null if you started some thread and put it asleep for a few seconds; while its sleeping if someone backs out of the app it will be null.

Comment: thats is basically what you should do

Comment: I think a better approach would be to use a callback interface.

Comment: Yep. Checking `getActivity() != null` is normal. Activity is generally null when the fragment is detached (which usually happens when the activity is destroyed or you've manually removed the fragment from the activity). What kind of feedback would you like to provide and where? If the activity is destroyed, what would you like to show? You probably *could* should a toast somewhere but I don't understand where that would be appropriate.

Comment: are the fragments still attached to the `Activity` when calling `getMyActivity` ?

Comment: Thanks @tyczj and others. The one problem I have with this approach is that it feels "dirty" (although programming in Android in general isn't soothing). I've edited the question to explain a common scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use some ParentFragment for example

```
public abstract class ParentFragment extends Fragment {

public Activity activity;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.activity = activity;
}

}
```

then you must owerride all yor fragments

```
public class SomeFragment extends ParentFragment {}
```

and use there activity for

```
activity.displayDialog(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the return value of getActivity () == null, then the Fragment is not attached in the FragmentManager of your parent activity.

A common mistake is to hold references of those fragments as object variables in the parent activity. This results in NPEs from Fragments.

I would recomend you to check whether this is your case.
If not, then:

1. See whether you are removing the Fragments from FragmentManager correctly
2. See whether you are adding the Fragments to the Framgnetmanager the right way.

if yes, remove the object variables and add the Fragments through the FragmentManager, see: http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/04/android-fragment-transaction.html

Hope this helps